# Selenium webdriver TypeError: element.isDisplayed is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an error:

*TypeError: element.isDisplayed is not a function*

When executing the following code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
  .build();

driver.get('https://www.test.com');
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(By.id('someButton')), 5000);
```

This is on my local machine using https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver and kicking off a server with:

*webdriver-manager start*

**My spec:**

Mac oSX Sierra 10.12.6

Chrome v60

The site I'm developing on is using AJAX to load pages to this could make a difference?

Comment: There is a issue with some version of selenium webdriver, safari driver. Could you test with Safari 9.1

Comment: Which Selenium binding are you using? `Java`?

Comment: I tested with Safari 10.1.2 and Firefox 54.0.1 and am getting the same error.

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager and this worked out of the box

Comment: You haven't specified what language you are using (should be added as a tag) and haven't responded to a request for that info so it's hard to tell. If I were to guess, it's likely that you are using the wrong syntax in the last line. There should be a reference to `ExpectedConditions` in there somewhere. Look at some wait sample code in your language and follow those examples.

Comment: I added JQuery and AJAX as tags, I don't normally need to specify JS if JQuery is specified but I added it for brevity. also there is a link to the NPM library which is Node therefore JS. I've gone through the code for JS and nothing's working which is why I'm posing the question here. Cheers

Comment: The Selenium binding must be JS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Problem**

`until.elementIsVisible(..)` needs a `WebElement` an not a `Locator` as a Argument.

**Solution**

Writing

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('someButton'))), 5000);
```

instead of

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(By.id('someButton')), 5000);
```

will solve the Problem.

**More Infos**

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2935